# How does Mathematica's LowpassFilter work?

Tags: implementation-details, signal-processing

I don't really understand the documentation for the `LowpassFilter[]` function in *Mathematica*. In the course I have about signal processing, low-pass filters come in many different forms and from different kinds of operations, so I was just wondering if someone could explain to me the math behind this specific function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the "Properties and Relations" section of the help file for `LowpassFilter` there is a big hint: it shows how `LeastSquaresFilterKernel` with a Hamming window gives the same answer as `LowpassFilter`. So this is a best-fit in the least-squares sense FIR (finite impulse response) filter. Digging a bit deeper into the `LeastSquaresFilterKernel` function, the calculation is is done by inverse FFT.

Putting this together, we can see that the default values for `LowpassFilter` calculate the $n$th order linear FIR filter that is closest to the specified frequency response (in a mean-squares sense), assuming preprocessing by a Hamming window.